# How can I download an embedded .swf file that involves the video.limelight.com site?

Tags: audio, download, flash, swf

I would like to extract the audio streams from www.springforesthealingfestevent.com - I can't figure out how to go about doing this. I usually can grab just about anything through Chrome using IDM - and I have even tried GetFLV on this site. Can anyone help?